# Scala Option with fold operation

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to use `fold` or `map` operation instead of `match` for `Option`.

I have a Option `val ao: Option[String] = xxxx` and a function `f: (String => Future[Option[T]])`

If I do pattern matching is:

```
ao match {
  case Some(t) => f(t)
  case None => Future.successful(None)
}
```

if I do map is:

```
ao map f getOrElse Future.successful(None)
```

But when I do fold, I got some following compiler errors:

```
ao.fold(Future.successful(None))(t => f(t))
```

about complaining `expression Future[Option[T]] doesn't confirm to Future[None.type]`

So why map works here but fold not, did I miss something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason for this is that Scala is trying to derive the return type `None.type` which is kind of like `Nil` for lists in the sense that only one object (`None`) exists and is upcast in all situations because it is `Option[Nothing]`. To get around this, you should explicitly define the types.

Here's the [Scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@fold[B]%28ifEmpty:=%3EB%29%28f:A=%3EB%29:B) for `fold` :

> `fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B`
>   Returns the result of applying f to this scala.Option's value if the scala.Option is nonempty. Otherwise, evaluates expression ifEmpty.

The compiler thinks `[B]` is `None.type`. so try calling it this way :

```
ao.fold[Future[Option[T]]](Future.successful(None))(t => f(t))
```

or calling it with a type ascription :

```
ao.fold(Future.successful(None: Option[T]))(t => f(t))
```

Comment: Using Option.empty[T] is an alternative to using a type ascription.